# Opencv SUFR feature detection. Is it reliably enough?

Tags: opencv

I want to develop an app, it needs to search similar pictures from back-end according to a uploaded picture, just like google's "search by image" function
[image]

As far as I know, opencv can handle this kind of thing, 
e.g Mean Shift, Contours Match . SUFT...  and seems SUFT is the best one.
But now I'm worried about whether can use it in enterprise product or whether it is reliably enough ? As I'm not just write a hello world program now and suppose the detection error rate is not too high !

If anyone who ever use this in your project before, expect you could share your experience.

Comment: share your experience?? is that a problem related to coding/programming?

Comment: yes, i need to know whether can use it for commercial usage

Answer (score 0):

It is not matter of reliability of OpenCV itself, it is a matter of reliability of the algorithms it uses.
Will it detect reliably 100% of the pictures, no matter what colors, shapes etc? - no it will not.
Will it be pretty much reliable, if you use it the right way? - Yes it will

Regarding the use in enterprise product - if you are asking about the license, then yes, it is free for commercial use.

I suggest you to read [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) and of course a lot of things [here](http://opencv.org)